# Get current progress of rsync daemon

Tags: rsync

I am running rsync process as a daemon. Rsync tool does not accept `--progress` and `--daemon` options together. I thought to parse the `/var/log/messages` and `rsyncd.log` file, is it a correct approach ? Is there any other possibility to get the current progress of the synced data ?

### Current usage of rsync -

```
rsync --daemon --config="/etc/rsyncd1.conf" --address=10.2.2.3
```

### After adding --progress option

```
rsync -v --progress --daemon --config="/etc/rsyncd1.conf" --address=10.2.2.3
```

Starting rsync [10.2.2.3]:  rsync: --progress: unknown option (in daemon mode)
(Type "rsync --daemon --help" for assistance with daemon mode.)
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(1005) [client=3.0.6]
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: It were a good feature request. Try to submit it by rsync devs.

Answer (score 1):

What about following workaround?

I've made a [script](https://libbits.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/get-total-rsync-progress-using-python/), that calculates the whole rsync progress in Python. You could modify it to send needed info to syslog or whatever suits your needs and run it as daemon.

Comment: Actually, I want to run rsync as a daemon. This is required because another process(s) are adding/modifying the data at the source site. so, I cannot start/stop rsync after some interval.